# Compare and assign numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers, compare, underscore.js, libraries

This procedure has likely been covered on SO in some form but I do not know how to find it.

I would like to compare one value with two others and assign a variable ideally in the same step.

In my case, I have a user Id (A) and two sample user ids ( B and C )

Either B or C in this situation must be equal to A.

I want to check if A == B or A == C and then set a variable (other) to the B or C id that DOES NOT equal A.

I know I could do

```
 if (A == B) {
   var other = C;
   return other
 } 
 else {
   var other = B
   return other
 }
```

Simple enough but does anyone know of a more efficient way? Any JS libraries are allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a [ternary condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var other = A == B ? C : B;
```

In this case, if `A` and `B` are the same, `other` will be set to `C`, otherwise it'll be set to `B`.

Answer (score 2):

> Simple enough but does anyone know of a more efficient way?

You can use the `if` condition what you are using presently or you can use the `ternary` operator. Both are having the same performance. Its just the matter of readability to what you want to use. <strike>As far as performance is concerned both the ways are almost equally efficient.</strike>

Just saw this [JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/ternary-vs-switch) and found that if condition is faster than ternary condition.